# jQuery pick up "enter" while in certain text elements and intercept parent form's submit event

Tags: jquery, forms, input

When I'm in certain text fields I want to be able to stop the propagation of the "enter" keypress.

Basically as long as I'm certain inputs I don't want the form that they're in to submit, and I need to intercept it. (The form is split into "windows". If they're not in the last window (`.win2`) then I don't want them to be able to hit enter and submit the form without realising they're only on the first window.

I hope that makes sense.

Here's what I have:

```
$(".win1 :input").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The keyup event gets fired, but I don't think that the `return false` works appropriately. Using `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` doesn't work either. Is there an easy way to stop the `submit` event from triggering on the form by listening to "enter" key presses?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace your input type="submit" by a normal button, which will do something like `$("form").submit();` if the data is legal, and otherwise the submit is never triggered.

Normally this should work:

```
$(".win1 :input").keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which === 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Niels, that's a good idea, was just interested if there was a way you could intercept. Obviously not, it'll have to be something a bit more contrived then. :) Yeah, I thought that would be the case too, but it doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? When you hit enter on .win1:input, it submits the form? This shouldn't happen, more details may be needed.

Comment: @DavidHoude, you're right, I wrote out a jsfiddle and it definitely intercepts the submit event... I don't have a clue why it wasn't working on the live site! Well anyway, I've used a variation on Niels solution in the end, so thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this example:

```
   <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function CancelSubmit(e)
  {
    var keynum
    var ret;
    if(window.event) // IE
    {
        keynum = e.keyCode
    }
    else if(e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
    {
        keynum = e.which
    }

    if(keynum == 13)
    {
        var content = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML =   content + "<p>submit canceled</p>";
        ret = false;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = true;
    }
    return ret;

  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>CANCEL SUBMIT</h1>

    <form method="post" action="Test-Submit.html">
    <input type="text" onkeypress="return CancelSubmit(event)" />
    <input type="text" onkeypress="return CancelSubmit(event)" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```